# split a string on a separator

Tags: lua

I have a string like `first part;second part`. I want to split it on the `;` and return the second part. Everything works fine with:

```
start = mystring:find(';')
result = mystring:sub(start)
```

But I was hoping to do it on one line:

```
result = mystring:sub(mystring:find(';'))
```

It doesn't throws an error but it is not returning the expected result. Not a big issue as it works fine on two lines of code but understanding why it's not working on the oneliner will help me to better understand how lua works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also work:

```
result = mystring:sub((mystring:find(';')))
```

The extra parentheses ensure that `sub` is called with only one argument, so it will use the default (the end of `mystring`) for the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

`find` actually returns two values, which are the start and end indices of where the string you looked for is. In this case, both indices are 11.
When you then pass these two indices to `sub`, you get a substring that both starts and ends at 11, so you only get ';'.

Comment: And any magic to pass only the first index  to the sub() function without first assigning it to a variable? Like `mystring:sub(mystring:find(';')[1])` (which, of course doesn't work)

Comment: @ripat lhf already answered this. Also take a look at this page: [http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin). You may gain further insight on a better solution, just in case your string comes to have more than two parts, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
s="first part;second part"  
print(s:match(";(.-)$"))
```

or this:

```
print(s:sub(s:find(";")+1,-1))
```

Comment: Less verbose indeed. But I tend to avoid using regex that are usually slower that string functions. As for the match() function wouldn't the `';(.-)$'` pattern suffice?

Comment: Just did some timing and find+sub is about 6 times faster than match on this one. So I will stick to the find+sub thingie.

Comment: Bingo. That's what I was asking. Thanks.